# Inconsistent handling of "final" modifier used in Groovy closure

Tags: groovy

I'm seeing different handling of "final" modifier in current stable Groovy (v3.0.7): identical code block which checks for condition and sets final variable works fine in regular code and fails when used in closure.

Example:

```
public List<Integer> test(String argument) {
    final value1
    if (argument == 'A') {
        value1 = 1
    } else {
        value1 = 2
    }
    
    [1, 2].collect { i ->
        final value2
        if (argument == 'A') {
            value2 = 1 // <-- error
        } else {
            value2 = 2
        }
    
        i + value2 
    }
}

test('A')
```

In Groovy console following error is displayed:

```
The variable [value2] may be uninitialized
. At [12:13]  at line: 12, column: 13
```

Am I missing something or this is an issue with Groovy?

Code works when "if" block is replaced with ternary operator:

```
final value2 = argument == 'A' ? 1 : 2
```

This seems to confirm that this is Groovy bug.

I have tested with other versions:

- 2.4.7, 2.4.12 - works
- 2.5.3, 2.5.11 - fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is this [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8346?jql=project%20%3D%20GROOVY%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22final%20uninitialized%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC) with Groovy.

In [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8346?focusedCommentId=16195665&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16195665), Paul King answers a question ("why is it working with 2.4.x ?") re: the Final Variable Analyzer (FVA):

> FVA is a 2.5 feature!  In 2.4 there are only rudimentary checks and Groovy ignores many violations. We currently have some false positives in the 2.5 implementation though that we need to get rid of.